# Почему не отображается элемент div в Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alfresco, yahoo

При заполнении элемента формы происходит поиск данных по значению. Во время поиска должно отобразиться текстовое поле вроде "Processing values", а после окончания поиска оно должно исчезнуть или при отрицательном результате вместо него должна появиться другая надпись.

В Firefox всё работает, в Google Chrome во время поиска надпись "Processing values" не отображается. Отображается только надпись после окончания поиска.

Пример вызова функции добавления div:

```
DisplayInfoBox(field, "Processing values");    
var data = Alfresco.forms.validation.validateBucAdn(buc, adn);
if (data.isValid == "true") {
  valid = "valid";
  DisplayValidBox(field, "Value is " + valid + " (" + data.validMsg + ")");
} else {
  valid = "invalid";
  DisplayErrorBox(field, "Value you've entered is " + valid + " (" + data.invalidMsg + "). ");
}
```

Сама функция:

```
function DisplayMsgBox (field, message, style) {
  var div = YAHOO.util.Dom.get(field.id + "errordiv");
  if (div != null) {
    field.parentNode.removeChild(div);
  }

  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', field.id + "errordiv");
  div.className = "help-text";
  div.setAttribute('style', style);
  div.innerHTML = message;
  field.parentNode.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Можно ли как то функцию DisplayMsgBox переписать на jquery или dojo ?

Comment: Что вы передаете параметром field? И не нужен здесь никакой jquery абсолютно.

Comment: @KunAguero, пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос [mcve].

Comment: передаю элемент (объект) к которому надо присоединить новый элемент div

Comment: по сути такой же элемент div